# Arrayformula treating checkboxes of column A as one entity. It updates the timestamp of all checkboxes to the current timestamp

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using an array formula to auto-populate a timestamp if a checkbox in the column A is checked right next to a record.
But, I am having issues with it. As, when a new checkbox is checked in column A. It suddenly updates the timestamp of all the already checked boxes to the current timestamp.
In other words; right now, the array is treating the whole range as 1 entity. So, change in the state of any checkbox in column A; triggers the column B to update all the timestamps to the current timestamp.

Formula I am using in column B

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A2:A=True, NOW(),""))
```

I tried the Today() function; still, no luck.

demo sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bNVhTGRbCgQyy7QswzAR2zx-_LpUJP93vDV4zqo5DSA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOW` and `TODAY` are volatile functions that cant be controlled or stopped. they recalculate automatically on the background either in set intervals of every minute, hour or any change:

[image]

that said, this issue cant be solved by any means with internal formulae so you will need a **[script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lgWd.png)**